# TNS-12505: TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor after shutting down one of the DB instance

Tags: oracle12c

My DB machine has three instance, I had shutdown the 'EDWDBS1' only (not the whole database) in the RMAN interface by using

```
shutdown immediate
```

But when I want to reconnect to/startup 'EDWDBS1', it throws ORA-12505 error either in sqldeveloper or sqlplus or RMAN. Alrd tried to check the tnsnames.ora and listener.ora, but I still got no idea about that.

Here is my listener.ora

```
# copyright (c) 1997 by the Oracle Corporation
# 
# NAME
#   listener.ora
# FUNCTION
#   Network Listener startup parameter file example
# NOTES
#   This file contains all the parameters for listener.ora,
#   and could be used to configure the listener by uncommenting
#   and changing values.  Multiple listeners can be configured
#   in one listener.ora, so listener.ora parameters take the form
#   of SID_LIST_<lsnr>, where <lsnr> is the name of the listener
#   this parameter refers to.  All parameters and values are
#   case-insensitive.

# <lsnr>
#   This parameter specifies both the name of the listener, and
#   it listening address(es). Other parameters for this listener
#   us this name in place of <lsnr>.  When not specified,
#   the name for <lsnr> defaults to "LISTENER", with the default
#   address value as shown below.
#
# LISTENER =
#  (ADDRESS_LIST=
#   (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))
#   (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=PNPKEY)))   

# SID_LIST_<lsnr>
#   List of services the listener knows about and can connect 
#   clients to.  There is no default.  See the Net8 Administrator's
#   Guide for more information.
#
# SID_LIST_LISTENER=
#   (SID_LIST=
#   (SID_DESC=
#           #BEQUEATH CONFIG
#          (GLOBAL_DBNAME=salesdb.mycompany)
#          (SID_NAME=sid1)          
#          (ORACLE_HOME=/private/app/oracle/product/8.0.3)
#           #PRESPAWN CONFIG
#         (PRESPAWN_MAX=20)
#     (PRESPAWN_LIST=
#           (PRESPAWN_DESC=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(POOL_SIZE=2)(TIMEOUT=1))
#         )
#        )
#       )

# PASSWORDS_<lsnr>
#   Specifies a password to authenticate stopping the listener.
#   Both encrypted and plain-text values can be set.  Encrypted passwords
#   can be set and stored using lsnrctl.  
#     LSNRCTL> change_password
#       Will prompt for old and new passwords, and use encryption both
#       to match the old password and to set the new one.
#     LSNRCTL> set password
#   Will prompt for the new password, for authentication with 
#       the listener. The password must be set before running the next
#       command.
#     LSNRCTL> save_config
#       Will save the changed password to listener.ora. These last two
#       steps are not necessary if SAVE_CONFIG_ON_STOP_<lsnr> is ON.
#       See below.
#
# Default: NONE
#
# PASSWORDS_LISTENER = 20A22647832FB454      # "foobar"

# SAVE_CONFIG_ON_STOP_<lsnr>
#   Tells the listener to save configuration changes to listener.ora when
#   it shuts down.  Changed parameter values will be written to the file,
#   while preserving formatting and comments.
# Default: OFF
# Values: ON/OFF
#
# SAVE_CONFIG_ON_STOP_LISTENER = ON

# USE_PLUG_AND_PLAY_<lsnr>
#   Tells the listener to contact an Onames server and register itself
#   and its services with Onames.
# Values: ON/OFF
# Default: OFF
#
# USE_PLUG_AND_PLAY_LISTENER = ON

# LOG_FILE_<lsnr>
#   Sets the name of the listener's log file.  The .log extension
#   is added automatically.
# Default=<lsnr>
#
# LOG_FILE_LISTENER = lsnr

# LOG_DIRECTORY_<lsnr>
#   Sets the directory for the listener's log file.
# Default: <oracle_home>/network/log
#
# LOG_DIRECTORY_LISTENER = /private/app/oracle/product/8.0.3/network/log

# TRACE_LEVEL_<lsnr>
#   Specifies desired tracing level.
# Default: OFF
# Values: OFF/USER/ADMIN/SUPPORT/0-16
#
# TRACE_LEVEL_LISTENER = SUPPORT

# TRACE_FILE_<lsnr>
#   Sets the name of the listener's trace file. The .trc extension
#   is added automatically.
# Default: <lsnr>
#
# TRACE_FILE_LISTENER = lsnr

# TRACE_DIRECTORY_<lsnr>
#   Sets the directory for the listener's trace file.
# Default: <oracle_home>/network/trace
#
# TRACE_DIRECTORY_LISTENER=/private/app/oracle/product/8.0.3/network/trace
# CONNECT_TIMEOUT_<lsnr>
#   Sets the number of seconds that the listener waits to get a 
#   valid database query after it has been started.
# Default: 10
#
# CONNECT_TIMEOUT_LISTENER=10
```

tnsnames.ora

```
EDWDBD1 = (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = HKHPEDWDBSDEV01)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = EDWDBD1)
    )
  )

EDWDBS1 = (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = HKHPEDWDBSDEV01)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = EDWDBS1)
    )
  )

EDWDBU1 = (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = HKHPEDWDBSDEV01)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = EDWDBU1)
    )
  )

EDWPDBD1 = (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = HKHPEDWDBSDEV01)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = EDWPDBD1)
    )
  )
```

Result of lsnrctl status

```
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on 11-FEB-2019 18:43:54

Copyright (c) 1991, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                11-FEB-2019 18:09:09
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 34 min. 45 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/db_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/HKHPEWDBSDEV01/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=HKHPEWDBSDEV01)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "7a114ab24bf177a5e055315d54627e2c" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "edwdbd1", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "EDWDBU1" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "EDWDBU1", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "EDWDBU1XDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "EDWDBU1", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "edwdbd1" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "edwdbd1", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "edwdbd1XDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "edwdbd1", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "edwpdbd1" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "edwdbd1", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Comment: `rman` is used for backups, not to "stop an instance". Please **[edit]** your question and show us the command you used to stop that instance

Comment: Mentioning rman is just wanna indicate that I cannot connect to edwdbs1 anymore after shutting down the instance. I used shutdown immediate to stop stat instance.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you are trying to start your instance remotely. In your listener.ora you don't have a static service configured, so you can't connect remotely (via TCP/IP) to the instance as the listener doesn't know about that instance.
In order to start the instance you should be connected locally (via SSH) and set all necessary environment variables (ORACLE_HOME, ORACLE_SID, PATH) and use OS authentication (usually be member of dba group) and run:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

and

```
startup;
```

Also you can use password file authentication but this is another story.